# Why do READ methods in Python and FREAD methods in C display different data？

Tags: python, c, file, io

I first open the file in python's “rb” mode ，and then i use “read” method to show the binary data for files. The file is 39 KB large.

Python code is：

```
aaa = open('C:\simfile\\testphoto.jpg','rb')
a = aaa.read()
print(len(a))  #39038
print(a)
```

The result of the Python code is
[image]

As you can see, the binary form of the file is “\xff \xd8 \xff  \xe0 ......”
Next, I use the C language's FREAD and read methods to read the file and print its binary form.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

   FILE *fp;

    //cout<<sizeof(char)<<endl;
   /* 打开文件用于读写 */
   fp = fopen("D:\CbProject\testphoto2.jpg", "rb");
   /* 写入数据到文件 */
   //fwrite(c, strlen(c) + 1, 1, fp);
   /* 查找文件的开头 */
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    int mysize = 39038+1;

    rewind(fp);
      char buffer[mysize];
   /* 读取并显示数据 */
   fread(buffer, mysize, 1, fp);
   //int fd = open("D:\CbProject\testphoto2.jpg", O_RDONLY);

  // read(fd,buffer,39039);

   for(int i = 0;i<mysize;i++)
   {
        printf("%2x  ", buffer[i] );
        //cout<<i << "  ";
   }


   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

The result of C language is:
[image]

[image]

why？
what's more,C:\simfile\testphoto.jpg and C:\simfile\testphoto.jpg ，They are the same file

Comment: Why are the file names different ? Are you sure you’re not looking at two different files ?

Comment: They are all the same file. sorry.

Comment: I suggest you check whether the `fopen` call in the C program actually succeeds, i.e. add `if (fp == NULL) ...report error...` immediately after the `fopen` call. Since you have backslashes in the file name which you have not escaped it's probably trying to open a non-existent file (specifically the `\t` will be converted to a tab character).

Comment: The `using namespace std;` is invalid in C (it is C++). See [n1570](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer C standard, and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) or some related web site. If possible, compile your C code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
fp = fopen("D:\CbProject\testphoto2.jpg", "rb");
```

In C one starts an escape sequence within a string with the escape character `\`. The escape sequence consists of at least two characters, the most well-known example is presumably `\n` for a newline character.

To get an actual backslash in a string literal, use the escape sequence `\\`.

Therefore, the line should look more like this:

```
fp = fopen("D:\\CbProject\\testphoto2.jpg", "rb");
```

Some additional remarks:

- the compiler usually warns about unknown escape sequences.
- as mentioned in the comments, check file operations for error codes
- `fseek` and `rewind` are not necessary, because the file is opened at the start anyway
- since the question is tagged with `C` - unlike in `C++` there are no namespace declarations in C
- since the file length seems to be 39038 (see the output of your Python program), you should read 39038 and not 39038 + 1 bytes

Applying the above, your sample code could look slightly different as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MYSIZE 39038

int main(void)
{

    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen("c:\\simfile\\testphoto2.jpg", "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[MYSIZE];
    if(fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        printf("%2x  ", buffer[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```